# How does Distributed Shared Memory work in the presence of cache and registers?

Tags: distributed-computing, distributed-system

I recently read a few papers describing DSM.

Some of them tried to provide a Sequential consistency. I understand how the algorithm works and how it utilizes the page fault handler to accomplish it. But one thing puzzles me is that even though the memory itself is Sequential consistency, the cache and register one each machine may break the sequential consistency model.

**How does it work with cache/registers?**

Even the DSM, supporting relaxed consistency ( like TreadMarks paper ), which does all synchronization in the Lock() / Unlock operations, it still has the same problem:

**How does it handle cache and register to prevent private copy on each machine?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### DSM is to be extended into a DCSM  <sup>( + best with smart *beyond*-NUMA controls )</sup>

A Distributed Coherent Shared Memory ( DCSM ) architecture, as a form of such suitable memory architecture, where a physically separate areas of memory
can be still addressed as one contiguous, logically shared address space.

For this concept to work as requested above, the word "**Coherent**" is the key ( and the NUMA / L1, L2, { L3 | local-memory } management controls all the filigree CPU intrinsics, from registers to CPU-local caches and memory ).

Industry available robust DCSM implementations must have solved the very consistency issue, in order to ever become feasible, and the user-view of such underlying DCSM system is thus just a view of a big / fat monolythic-(abstract)-host, where in spite of so many thousands of CPU-s and all the physically distributed computing resources ( spanning from CPU-s, DRAM-memory-blocks, all-kinds of IO-devices, incl. storage, all network-interfaces, etc. ), the whole DCSM-integrated infrastructure still remains a coherent highly performant *"super"*-host.

So no direct user-code interactions are expected or needed and one can spin-up any of the legacy-code, now having some **8000+ CPU-s** + **XYZ [TB] RAM as a coherent space for pure in-RAM computing** ( where XYZ can recently scale to ranges above a few hundreds, if not thousands, limited more by one's budget than in principle ).

One can easily feel, what to expect from such computing device, having under the hood such a beast with such an immense computing resources, where the user-code need not and does not bother how / where the actual resource is physically harnessed, as the O/S-level abstraction keeps the user-code to assume, it is just there and coherently runs *"across"* such a distributed compute-resources DCSM infrastructure.

Isn't this great?

Comment: So we do have to solve the problem caused by cache/register to provide the consistency model, right? This is not mentioned at all in papers (Like TreadMarks). That's why I am wondering. Also what consistency model does industrial DCSM usually provides? I don't think sequential consistency(CS) is feasible at all in terms of performance. To provide CS, not only the shared memory should be CS, but also we need to flush register/cache every time we try to write to the memory, right?

Comment: Long story short, this goes way beyond S/O format. Yes, while I agree that many principal Computer Science issues have been both raised & solved literally decades ago, Keleher et al have been working in epochs, wher hardware was uncomparably simpler ( { NUMA- | cache- | super-scalar pipeline optimised silicon design-}-wise ) than contemporary silicon designs. The point is in having deployed a such distributed system design, that has solved the DCSM transparently to the user-code and we can both stay in a peace of mind ( and forget about DCSM nitty-gritties ) & rely on it's service implemented.

Comment: Anyway, thank you to mention RICE / Keleher et al papers - have made me back to day, when Digital Equipment Corporation + Ultrix O/S existed, when DSM was a way to go beyond an exclusively rare & expensive SMP hardware, when ISO-OSI-L2 Asynchronous Transfer Mode 48+5 byte cells were the ultimately best & smartest match for SDH/SONET globally synchronous transport infrastructure ( later lost in ex-post ToS labelled best-effort jittery delivery services ). Lovely days indeed, full of bright minds & smart ideas :o) **Needless to ask, why has the crowd moved in direction with way poorer toys ...**